# Linq query does not return data

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have the following query in SQL which returns 5 rows of data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.PhoneNumber, 'Waiting to be sent'
FROM DistributionGroupMembers dgm
JOIN Contacts c on dgm.ContactId = c.Id
JOIN DistributionGroups dg on dgm.DistributionGroupId = dg.Id
WHERE dg.Id IN (
    SELECT DistributionGroupId
    FROM DistributionGroupInSms
    WHERE SmsId = 40
)
```

When I try to run the adequate query in C# using LINQ it won't return anything:

```
int[] groupIDs = await _db.DistributionGroupInSms.Where(dgis => dgis.SmsId == message.Id).Select(g => g.Id).ToArrayAsync();
var recipients = await (from dgm in _db.DistributionGroupMembers
                        join c in _db.Contacts on dgm.ContactId equals c.Id
                        join dg in _db.DistributionGroups on dgm.DistributionGroupId equals dg.Id
                        where groupIDs.Contains(dg.Id)
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = c.Id,
                            FN = c.FirstName,
                            LN = c.LastName,
                            PN = c.PhoneNumber,
                            SR = "Waiting to be sent"
                        }).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh sorry, groupIDs is an array of integers. See the updated question. It does get a value from the DB

Comment: Debug and remove the joins one after another and you'll find out where the problem is.

Comment: Are any of the fields from the data, firstname, lastname or phonenumber, nullable?  You may need to check for null values otherwise output may not occur.  i.e. FN = c.FirstName == NULL ? "" : c.FirstName;

Comment: I figured it out, in the `select` clause by getting the `groupIDs` I selected `Id` instead of another field in the table called `DistributionGroupId`. Thanks everyone for the input

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply do a join:

```
int[] groupIDs = await _db.DistributionGroupInSms.Where(dgis => dgis.SmsId == message.Id).Select(g => g.Id).ToArrayAsync();
var recipients = await (from dgm in _db.DistributionGroupMembers
                        join c in _db.Contacts on dgm.ContactId equals c.Id
                        join dg in _db.DistributionGroups on dgm.DistributionGroupId equals dg.Id
                        join gIds in groupIDs on gIds equals dg.Id
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = c.Id,
                            FN = c.FirstName,
                            LN = c.LastName,
                            PN = c.PhoneNumber,
                            SR = "Waiting to be sent"
                        }).Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

Comment: thanks. I added `join gIDs in groupIDs on dg.Id equals gIDs` and removed the where statement but it didn't make any difference

Comment: may I know whats the array contents in groupIDs like when debugging

Comment: It's a single int for example with value 38

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, in the `select` clause by getting the `groupIDs` I selected `Id` instead of another field in the table called `DistributionGroupId`. Thanks everyone for the input